# Apply the new activity tab design in the network profile as well

Tags: feature-request, design, stackexchange.com, network-profile

Some time ago, the profile page got a revamp on all Stack Exchange sites, while se.com got left behind. No change whatsoever for many many years.

I don't ask for the whole revamp to be done there, just one specific change, of the activity tab. That's how it looks like on the sites:

[image: activity tab on one of SE sites]

And that's how it looks like in the network profile:

[image: activity tab on the network profile]

That's the old design, I hope it's time to upgrade it. Posted example of someone with no activity, because part of the upgrade was to make the message make more sense: "This user has no badges" instead of "no activity found".